# Reading from a file location contained in package

Tags: java, android, file, exception

I have a .txt file which contains a list of stuff I want to store in an Array and use throughout my application. To achieve this I created the following class:

```
public class Sort {

ArrayList<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>();

public Sort() throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("/home/scibor/coding/src/com/myapp/readThis.txt"));
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        sorted.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }
}
}
```

So I have a .txt file with a bunch of stuff in it, and then I create this class specifically for that case. Now when I want to access these things in the .txt file in an ArrayList in one of my other classes, I figure:

```
Sort sort = new Sort();
sort.sorted; //can use the arrayList like so
```

Instead I get a message that says `UnhandledException: java.io.IOException`

I've tried several variations of this using try/catch, BufferedReader with try/catch/finally and ultimately all of them have some sort of error pertaining to the Exceptions that are raised by reading in a file. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: As per one of the suggestions, I have tried a radically different approach as below:

```
public class Sort {

List<String> sorted;

public Sort(Context context){

    sorted = new ArrayList<String>();
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream read = assetManager.open("readThis.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(read));
        while(reader.readLine() != null){
            sorted.add(reader.readLine());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This seems to get me further, and is probably very close to the correct answer. When I create `Sort mySortedObject = new Sort(this);` there are no errors generated. When I finally access the ArrayList though, as follows:

```
for(String name: mySortedObject.sort){
    if(name.equals("Whatever"){
        //run this
            }
        }
    }
```

I get a NullPointerException on the line containing the `if` statement. So the object was successfully created...but not quite?

EDIT: The "readThis.txt" file is located in `/assets`

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: In the case above the error occurs at `Sort sort = new Sort();`

Comment: Does your `Sort` class have a `Sort()` constructor?

Comment: Coding wise something is wrong, I'm working in IntelliJ and it's underlining the `Sort sort...` line telling me before compiling even that there's something wrong with it, when I move the cursor over for more details, it tells me `Unhandled Exception:...`

Comment: @Curtis yes, sorry, I was copying line by line to exclude irrelevant things, the main part of the code is in fact a constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the file "/home/scibor/coding/src/com/myapp/readThis.txt" does not exist on your phone (and for a good reason). You will need to add your .txt as an asset to your project and load it using the [AssetManager.open()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)-method

Edit:

In your edited code, your `NullPointerException` is caused by you calling .readLine() twice in each iteration.

Solution:

```
String line = null;
while(true){
     line = reader.readLine();
     if (line == null) break;
     sorted.add(line);
 }
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems like the way to go, I have modified the code in the question but am getting a NullPointerException on one of the lines, is there any glaring error in my code?

Comment: @mike Yeah, there was a little error in your code. See my edited answer. And upvote and accept if it helped.

Comment: Still NullPointerException, but I think I can get this to work, very helpful